# Copy the second value in each row to a specific column

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs, google-apps

Given the table:

```
A  B  C  D  E
x  x  52 50 48 ...
67 69 71 73 75 ...
57 x  56 49 48 ...
62 x  x  66 66 ...
```

How to find the **second** number from the **left** in each line (marked here with *)?

```
A    B    C    D    E       Z
x    x    52  *50*  48 ...  50
67  *69*  71   73   75 ...  69
57   x   *56*  49   48 ...  56
62   x    x   *66*  66 ...  66
```

so that finally for each row the marked number will appear in Column Z.

Comment: Put this in column Z: `=index(filter(A1:Y1, isnumber(A1:Y1)), 1, 2)`

Comment: @SpiderPig, works like a charm. I just had to exchange the "," with ";". Thank you so much !! How to rep?

Comment: So unfortunately I can't do anything fpr SpiderPig, but say THANKS! Sometimes a small help can make all the difference... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Put this in column Z: `=index(filter(A1:Y1, isnumber(A1:Y1)), 1, 2)`.
Depending on the language you choose in the spreadsheet settings you may have to change `,` to `;`.
e.g. for french and german it's `;`. For english it's `,`.